# How to properly configure Docker to deliver better performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I'm responsible for developing a content delivery application, recently we have shifted our app from a monolithic architecture to microservices but unfortunately, we are facing an unbelievable slowness in getting responses from API. the API takes like 11 seconds to get a result, and if we have 2 requests on the same mobile app page, it takes forever! the service is not asking for any data from other local services.

The old specs (Monolithic):

1. DB is MSSSQL Server
2. Backend code .Net Framework
3. Restful API
4. Mobile App React Native
5. 2 AWS EC2 dual core and 4 gb ram for each

The current specs (Microservices):

1. DB is MySQL
2. Backend .Net Core
3. Restful API
4. Mobile App Flutter
5. 2 AWS ECS dockers for each service under the load balancer also dual-core and 4 gb per each service.

This is my Docker file:

```
# Define base image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env

# Copy project files
WORKDIR /source
COPY ["Magazines_Service/*.csproj", "./Magazines_Service.csproj"]

# Restore
RUN dotnet restore "./Magazines_Service.csproj"

# Copy all source code
COPY . .

# Publish
WORKDIR /source/Magazines_Service
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish

# Runtime
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=build-env /publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Magazines_Service.dll"]
```

All hosting is on AWS

I read something about docker-compose but haven't dig deeper (I'm very new to docker and microservice architecture so your help definitely an addition to me).

Comment: What are you using to host the containers? Sounds like they could be sleeping and your requests are causing them to spin-up. After you hit the API once, are subsequent requests also just as slow?

Comment: @Tim thank you for your reply. The subsequent APIs are even slower.

Comment: @Tim we are using AWS ECS.